# How to filter content field in webform before sending?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have an issue on how to proceed in creating a filter/alert for users (any user may send webform) on the content of the messsage through webform (using drupal 6).

Let say someone goes to the form and types XXX within the message. I want to not let the user send webform or delete that specific content if that word/link/set of words are typed in.

If you know how to do it you may contact me directly too